# Can't move divs inside other div

Tags: html, css

I recently started to code and I wanted to code a calculator i JavaScript. I started to code HTML/CSS but I have a problem with divs, I can't move them inside the another div.

This is my HTML:

```css
.calc {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.title {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.5/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class=calc>
  <div class=title>Kalkulator</div>
  <div><input id="result" type="number"></div>
  <div><button class=btn-plus>+</button></div>
  <div><button class=btn-minus>-</button></div>
  <div><button class=btn-multi>*</button></div>
  <div><button cass=btn-div>/</button></div>
</div>
```

I wanted to change the position of buttons and input and I wanted to make a title bigger. I can't change its size nor move it tho.

Comment: How would you like the position of the buttons changed?

Answer (score 0):

Without further information it's hard to say what you're going for.

To answer one of your questions with confidence: you can change the size of your title with `font-size`.

I've also moved the buttons to be side-by-side by changing all their classes to `btn` and adding `float: left;`

```css
.calc {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.title {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.btn {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.5/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="calc">
  <div class="title">Kalkulator</div>
  <div><input id="result" type="number"></div>
  <div><button class="btn">+</button></div>
  <div><button class="btn">-</button></div>
  <div><button class="btn">*</button></div>
  <div><button cass="btn">/</button></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed out the quotation marks around the classes.

So this: `<div class=calc>` should look like this: `<div class="calc">`

I have moved the buttons under one `<div>` to align them on one line and corrected the setting of the `class` for each item.

```
<div class="calc">
  <div class="title">Kalkulator</div>
  <div><input id="result" type="number"></div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn-plus">+</button>
    <button class="btn-minus">-</button>
    <button class="btn-multi">*</button>
    <button class="btn-div">/</button>
</div>
```

If you want to make the font bigger, set the `.title { font-size: 20px; }`

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth you having a look at what the [`display` property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) does and what the difference between a [`<span>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp) and a [`<div>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp) is. There's loads of great resources out there.

See this [pen for a working example](https://codepen.io/andyusdigital/pen/wZeNXK).

CSS:

```
.calc {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.title {
  height: 20px;
}

button {
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px; // top right bottom left
}

.title,
.result {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.calc div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.5/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="calc">
  <div class="title">Kalkulator</div>
  <div class="result"><input id="result" type="number" /></div>
  <div><button class="btn-plus">+</button></div>
  <div><button class="btn-minus">-</button></div>
  <div><button class="btn-multi">*</button></div>
  <div><button class="btn-div">/</button></div>
</div>
```

Keep up the learning man! Good job on what you've got so far!